# Why can't my Yahoo mail account receive email sent by mutt?

Tags: email

Install mutt and mail:

```
sudo apt-get install mutt
echo "install gentoo" | mutt -s "gentoo installation handbook" -A  gentoo.pdf  xxxx@yahoo.com
```

I can't find email in my yahoo email.
Check the email with :

```
sudo cat /var/mail/debian
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  xxxx@yahoo.com
    Mailing to remote domains not supported

--1624330018-eximdsn-1608038189
Content-type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; debian

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;xxxx@yahoo.com
Status: 5.0.0

--1624330018-eximdsn-1608038189
Content-type: text/rfc822-headers
```

Fix the setting.

```
sudo  vim  /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf
dc_eximconfig_configtype="internet"  # previously, it is "local"
sudo service  exim4 restart
```

Try again with

```
echo "install gentoo" | mutt -s "gentoo installation handbook" -A  gentoo.pdf  xxxx@yahoo.com
```

Still no email in my yahoo email box.

```
sudo cat /var/mail/debian
Return-path: <debian@debian>
Received: from debian by debian with local (Exim 4.92)
    (envelope-from <debian@debian>)
    id 1lvWRG-000IZw-A1
    for xxxx@yahoo.com; Tue, 22 Jun 2021 10:46:58 +0800
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="1267179262-1624330018=:71419"
Subject: gentoo installation handbook
To: <xxxx@yahoo.com>
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 3.5)
Message-Id: <E1lvWRG-000IZw-A1@debian>
From: debian <debian@debian>
Date: Tue, 22 Jun 2021 10:46:58 +0800
X-Exim-DSN-Information: Due to administrative limits only headers are returned


--1624330018-eximdsn-1608038189--
```

How to fix then?

Comment: I don't know anything about what you're trying to do but Yahoo is notoriously sensitive to automatically generated emails. Sometimes they'll get flagged and never show up. I used to work for a company that sent system-generated emails and we had numerous clients with Yahoo email addresses who we had to coach through getting gmail addresses just to use our service. Sometimes whitelisting the sending domain helped, sometimes it didn't. Try whitelisting the sender's domain in your Yahoo email settings and see if that does it.

Comment: What kind of network are you sending this from? Home? Corporate? Datacenter?

Comment: Normal home network, adsl and pppoe.

Comment: Many email providers like Yahoo require you to have an app password, see this page scroll down to Yahoo section>>>>https://www.firetrust.com/products/mailwasher-pro/support/frequently-asked-questions#gmail-password-requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the rest of the non-delivery notification that you received. This time it probably says something different than before – so fix the new issue.

> Normal home network, adsl and pppoe

The bigger a mail provider is, the more spam it gets, so the stricter checks it performs for inbound mail. (Both Yahoo and Outlook/Hotmail especially so.)

First of all this means you have *very* little chance of successfully sending mail from a residential network (especially one that's known to use dynamic IP addresses). The recipient's mail system is likely to reject your whole IP address range, whether due to past abuse or due to the fact it's a home connection.

In fact, many residential ISPs will just outright *block* all outbound connections to port 25 (the SMTP mail exchange port). If your ISP does so, the block can sometimes be removed, sometimes not. No, you can't just change the port.

So if you want to talk to Yahoo*!*, your mail server needs to be hosted elsewhere – usually a server hosting company is a good choice. (Those are usually stricter about not letting their customers send spam, so Yahoo is more likely to accept mail from them.)

And in order to send mail from home, you'll need to relay mail through another mail server (a "smarthost"), i.e. have Exim submit mail like a desktop mail client would, with username & password and through a different SMTP port. (There are many examples online for configuring Exim to relay e.g. through your Gmail account, or through your personal mail server. There are even relay-only MTAs such as msmtp which might be more suitable.)

Second, your message has a "From" address that is completely made up: its domain name is literally just `debian`. Using a real domain name would probably help with convincing other mail providers that your message isn't spam. Using a domain name that has valid MX records (and even valid SPF records) would probably help *a lot.*

(And if you're relaying through another provider, you must use exactly the address that belongs to your account at that provider – e.g. Gmail only allows sending mail from your gmail.com address. In Exim you might need to use "rewriting" or "masquerading" to achieve this.)